# How to avoid DTO to domain conversion and vice versa in Spring boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, controller, dto

In my project I am getting values from UI, passing to Controller and to the service layer. Then I do the DTO to domain conversion, I feel that this is unnecessary and not a good design.

e.g. Here is my JSP:

```
<form:form id="parcelCondemnationCaseDetailsForm"
modelAttribute="parcelCondemnationCaseDetailsDTO">
<form:hidden path="prclSeqNum" />
<form:hidden path="condemnationStatusCode" />
<form:hidden id="isMDOTVerifiedMoveDateAvailable"
    path="mDOTVerifiedMoveDateAvailable" />
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <label for="finalDisposition">Final Disposition</label>
            <form:select class="form-control dirty _enableSaveDisable"
                id="finalDisposition" path="finalDisposition"
                disabled="${agSecurityFinalDisabled}"
                onchange="finalDispositionChange()">
                <form:option value="" select="select">Select</form:option>
                <form:option value="J">Judgement</form:option>
                <form:option value="V">Jury Verdict</form:option>
                <form:option value="S">Settlement</form:option>
                <form:option value="O">Other</form:option>
            </form:select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3" id="finalDispositionDescriptionDiv"
            style="display: none;">
            <label for="finalDispositionDescription" class="req-label">Final
                Disposition Description</label>
            <form:input type='text' id="finalDispositionDescription"
                class="form-control dirty _enableSaveDisable" aria-required="true"
                path="finalDispositionDescription" maxlength="50"
                disabled="${agSecurityFinalDisabled}" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <label for="finalDispositionDate">Final Disposition Date</label>
            <form:input type='text' id="finalDispositionDate"
                class="form-control lamdaDate dirty _addDate _pastPresent _enableSaveDisable"
                path="finalDispositionDate" disabled="${agSecurityFinalDisabled}" />

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <label for="closedDate">Closed Date </label>
            <form:input type='text' id="closedDate"
                class="form-control lamdaDate dirty _addDate _pastPresent  _enableSaveDisable"
                path="closedDate" disabled="${agSecurityFinalDisabled}" />

        </div>
    </div></form:form>
```

and this is my controller

```
    @PostMapping("/saveCaseDetails.htm")
public @ResponseBody String saveCaseDetails(ParcelCondemnationCaseDetailsDTO parcelCondemnationCaseDetailsDTO,
        ModelMap model) {
    String responseMessage = "";
    try {
        parcelCondemnationCaseDetailsDTO = parcelCondemnationCaseDetailsService
                .saveCaseDetails(parcelCondemnationCaseDetailsDTO);
        responseMessage = "success";
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error(
                "Error occured while saving Condemnation > Valuation at CondemnationValuationController.saveValuation",
                e);
        responseMessage = "Error occured while saving Case Details.";
    }
    return responseMessage;
}
```

and the service layer.

```
    public ParcelCondemnationCaseDetailsDTO saveCaseDetails(
            ParcelCondemnationCaseDetailsDTO parcelCondemnationCaseDetailsDTO) {
        ParcelCondemnation parcelCondemnation = ParcelCondemnationCaseDetailsMapper.INSTANCE
                .getCaseDetails(parcelCondemnationCaseDetailsDTO);
parcelCondemnationRepository.save(parcelCondemnation);
```

I do not see that I am adding any value while doing DTO to domain conversion.
So, my question is there any way I can just avoid using DTO, mappers and extra line of code?

Thanks for looking.

Answer (score 2):

Since your Entity is exactly your DTO, you can use `@JsonView` annotation in your controller and directly in your entity class, which can filter the fields you wish to show to your UI as response.

```
@PostMapping("/saveCaseDetails.htm")
@JsonView(View.Public.class)
public @ResponseBody String saveCaseDetail
...


@Entity
public ParcelCondemnation {
    
@JsonView(View.Public.class)
private String anyFieldtoShow;

private String anyFieldToNotShow;
...

public class Views {
    public static class Public {}
}
```

In this case, your response will show only the `anyFieldToShow` as an answer to any request to that enpoint annotated with the related `JsonView`.

Here is a better explanation:
[Baeldung tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-json-view-annotation)

And I know you can maybe use GraphQL, which unfortunately I don't have enough knowledge to talk about, but here it follows the link if you wish to go deep: [GraphQL doc](https://graphql.org/code/#java)

Comment: Thanks for your comments, however, how to handle the situation where I will have a date is UI and amounts represented in currency formats? The UI might send date as a string and current again as a string.

Comment: You are welcome. I didn't understand exactly what you meant, can you update your question with more details or create another one ?